# Can't attach photo with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I want to attach photo using paperclip. I have installed paper clip gem, and generated paper clip :photo. (I am using rails 3.1)

My user model have

```
has_attached_file :photo
```

My form is

```
 =form_for(@user, :html=>{:multipart => true}) do |f|
    %p
      Birthday:
      %br
      = f.date_select(:birthday,:start_year => 1940)
    %p
      Name:
      %br
      = f.text_field :name, :value=>@user.name
    %p
      Surname:
      %br
      = f.text_field :surname ,:value =>@user.surname
    %p
      Nickname:
      %br
      = f.text_field :nickname, :value=>@user.nickname
    %p
      About Myself:
      %br
      = f.text_area :about_myself, :value=>@user.about_myself
    %p
      =f.file_field :photo
    %p
      = f.submit "Update"
```

And my view has:

```
= image_tag @user.photo.url
```

But instead of image I have:

```
<img alt="Missing" src="/photos/original/missing.png">
```

What am I doing wrong? How to solve this problem?

Comment: any error messages, what's `$rails s` saying when it fails

Comment: Check the file system to see if the file is being saved. And yes, check the console logs.

Comment: @ZMorek how can I look error messages? server works fine. I am rather new to rails, so I dont know how to watch them(how to check console logs)

Comment: I cant find image in my file system

Comment: @Pavel when you run your rails server in your command line `$rails s` you can see the output to the command line live as it happens, additionally you can check `your_app_folder/logs/development.log` and see what happens when the error occurs

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/photos/original/missing
.png"): it only error i have, what to do now?

Comment: please , some1 help, i very need it for university project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set special

```
attr_accessible
```

before

```
has_attached_file :photo (in my case)
```

It worked for me